# Send a PDF attachment with email using Amazon SES in Python/Django

Tags: django, email, pdf, amazon-ses

I have my code for creating a PDF of a web page which can be downloaded by the user.
I want to send this PDF as attachment via mail using [Amazon SES](http://aws.amazon.com/ses/).

Thanks in advance!

Comment: have you tried to google for it ? unless you have a more specific question/problem about this it looks like the best resource

Answer (score 0):

I would just output/save the PDF in a temporary location on the server like in /tmp/hello.pdf then attach it to the email:

```
from django.core.mail import EmailMessage

email = EmailMessage('Hello', 'Body goes here', 'from@example.com', ['to1@example.com'])
email.attach_file('/tmp/hello.pdf')
email.send()
```

G

Comment: :thanks!!but,i am using amazon ses to send email(Not the one provided by dajngo).Also,i don't want to save my PDF to a temporary location.I want to create it and attach it on the fly.